# SQL Server: Delete and Backup TDE Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, tde

maybe the question is to trivial and that's why I can't find something online:

I need to make sure that a TDE encrypted database can be easily

- backed up and
- deleted

without touching any certificates or keys.

Am I right? Deleting and backing up is transparent as well as working with the data?

Thanks,
:-) Torsten

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The "transparent" part is just what it says on the tin. It's when you want to restore that you'll need the certificate handy.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Exactly my thoughts! :-)